# There is nothing to do/to be done

Tags: meaning

> 1 There is nothing to do here. = There is nothing worth doing here.
>
> 2 There is nothing to be done here. = There is nothing which should be
> done here.

Do you agree with my interpretations?

> 3 There is nothing to be seen here.

What does 3 mean? Does it mean there is nothing that can be seen OR there is nothing that should be seen?

Comment: (2) usually means "There is nothing we can do (to improve the situation)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> → There's nothing to do.
> = I'm so bored! There are no activities that I feel like doing.

> → There's nothing to be done.
> = I'm sorry. There's no way to improve the situation. It is what it is.

These are both very idiomatic phrases. The first phrase is associated with children. Here's [a delightful lo-fi reading of a children's book](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rllNRvz-gqA) that illustrates the phrase perfectly — note the irony that there are many things to do, but none that the character *wants* to do. The story ends in a pun on the word "nothing", which shouldn't be taken as its main meaning.

The second phrase is harder to find examples for spontaneously, but here's [a song in which it means that the past can't be changed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WC4yin0QpUs), and here's [a Simpsons clip in which it's the implied answer to the question, "What's to be done?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pVpCskFBrM), i.e. what solution is there? And here's [a transcript of a Star Trek episode](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/62.htm) that includes these lines:

> MCCOY: Unless Miranda can look down into his mind and turn it outward to us, we will lose Spock. Her knowledge of [Vulcan mind techniques] may be the only thing that could save Spock's sanity, perhaps even his life. There's nothing else to be done.

McCoy's line there, which includes "else", demonstrates very well the meaning, "We are trying our only option. Besides this, there are no options."

---

Because these two phrases are so idiomatic, it's hard to say whether the effect can be generalized to other active/passive pairs. For example, these two feel pretty much equivalent in meaning:

> → There's nothing to see here.
> → There's nothing to be seen here.

There's a slight difference of formality with the passive, but no difference in sense.

Comment: It is a police trope to say 'Move along! Nothing to see here!' when there may be a great deal that you want to see. So much depends on context.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That's true. If I had to recommend one, I'd probably go with the active because of that familiar scenario. However, it kind of has the same feeling as "nothing to do" -- there may be things to see, but nothing *worth* seeing or nothing that you're *going* to see (as the police insist). The passive, then, might suggest nothing that it's literally possible to see. If there is a systematic difference at all.